# Error: The subscription MyCompany doesn't have permissions to register the resource provider(s)

Tags: azure

I cannot deploy an application to Azure even though I am Global Admin for the new company Azure subscription.

When I try to add any resource from the Azuee Portal or from PowerShell i get this message

"The subscription MyCompany doesn't have permissions to register the respource provider(s):  Microsoft.DocumentDB

Where "Microsoft.DocumentDB" is an SQl resource.  I tried this with noSQl and API Management services and got the same error.

Any idea why?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Turns out that in order to install any resource there must be a resource installer for the type of resource.
And the resource installers are not installed in Azure by default.

Only the Subscription Admin can install resource installers.

Easiest way to do this is to login to Azure Portal as the Subscription Admin and add a resource of the type you want.
This automatically installs the resource installer for that type.  (Apparently this does not work for all resource types; see comment below)

That resource installer is now available to all users with resource install rights.

Comment: man, half of this is wrong, not only sub admin can do that, some of the resources won't even install resource providers for themselves automatically (Azure Container Registry, as an example)